# Swift 4 app crashes when open file from icloud

Tags: ios, swift, file, icloud

I have a problem that my app crashes when it is opening a file from iCloud. If I open this file from my app with a **Document Picker**, everything is fine. But if I try to open from outside my app, for example from iCloud or safari download it crashes. If I open it from local storage "my iphone" it is also working. It is interesting because it was good one week ago :)

So in AppDelegate, I've implemented the following method:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {}
```

According to the logs the crash occurs because the file does not exist.

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/twic1121.pgn
```

This is the result if I print the URL from the parameter. I think this means that the file is there.

But if i do this: `print(fm.fileExists(atPath: url.path))` then this is **false**.

So it is obvious that after `let dataFromFile = fm.contents(atPath: url.path)`
this is **nil**.

I have no idea what could be the problem here. So the real question here is why this is nil?

Comment: Try calling `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` on your URL first. (See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso)

Comment: This works if the file has already downloaded to the phone. So if there is a small cloud icon in the upright corner of the file this is not working, anyway I'm one step ahead than before, so thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know all the details either. Try to look at the `FileManager` methods `startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at:)`  and `isUbiquitousItem(at:)`. Also try using the URLs directly instead of getting the path.

Comment: It is interesting, because if I would like to open a file which is not downloaded yet, just the placeholder icon is there, if I try this from a Document Picker, then it downloads first and then opens. But from outside the app, if I tap on it, it just opens immediately (of course, the file does not exist at that point, just its icon).
I 've found already this startDownloadingUbiquitousItem before, but I don't understand why it hasn't got any callback? It just starts the download, but I don't know when it is finished. Thanks to your help, I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error can be many things, all not related to the class you are applying the code (AppDelegate) nor the methods you are calling.

<s>My guess is that **the URL you are calling is not correctly built** (not pointing to the correct object you are trying to point to). For many reasons.</s>

See if one of this reasons fix your issue:

<s>(1) The end of the URL you are calling had the suffix "pgn". If you are looking to load a picture, maybe the suffix is wrong. In that case it could have been some known and supported format like "png", "jpeg" or "jpg".</s>

<s>(2) The "%20"symbol at the middle of your code also lifts a flag. Does not seem to be a correct URL object of swift. Maybe the URL you are using is not represented in the correct way.</s>

<s>(3) com~apple~CloudDocs also lifts a flag, since it would unlikely have a "~" symbol in a URL passed. This also strongly suggests that maybe the URL you are using is not represented in the correct way.</s>

<s>I think your URL is not pointing to where you are trying to point to, resulting in the "does exist" method return false and the loading resulting in nil.</s>

If all of this does not fix your issue, post more details of the code. <s>Specially what method you are calling to build/create this URL object you are using, that points to:    `file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/twic1121.pgn`</s>

Comment: This URL is from the delegate method, that gets called when you open a file that has a registered file type with the application.

Comment: The URL is not the problem. `%20` is the correct way to encode spaces in an URL. And the `com~apple~CloudDocs` part is typical for URLs of files stored in iCloud. Also nobody said that it is supposed to be an image file - `pgn` is a common file format to store chess games.